# jQuery Datepicker Range with Cloned Form Elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, clone, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a dynamic form that can be cloned, but the Datepicker Custom Range function limits every clone's end date from the first start date element.

I am using the [SheepIt!](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB) plugin to clone my form elements.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YWdV7/15/

*Note: add/delete functions not working in fiddle, but example of date range limits as previously described

Initial function for first date fields and clone function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var container = $('#container').sheepIt(
    {
            separator: '',
            allowRemoveLast: true,
            allowRemoveCurrent: false,
            allowRemoveAll: false,
            allowAdd: true,
            allowAddN: false,
            maxFormsCount: 10,
            minFormsCount: 0,
            iniFormsCount: 1
        }   
        );
    });

    $(function() {
        $( ".date" ).datepicker({   
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "../../media/icons/calendar.png",          
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2011:2050',
            beforeShow: customRange 
        }); 
    });

    function customRange(input) {
        if ($(input).hasClass('end_date')) {
            var minDate = new Date($('.start_date').val());
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1)
            return {
                minDate: minDate
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Function to re-initiate datepicker when clone button is pressed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container_add').live('click', function() {  
    $('.date').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../../media/icons/calendar.png",          
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2011:2050',
        beforeShow: customRange 
    })

    function customRange(input) {
        if ($(input).hasClass('end_date')) {
            var minDate = new Date($('.start_date').val());
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1)
            return {
                minDate: minDate
            };
        }
    };

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things about your code:

- `$(function() {})` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {})`.
- `customRange(input)` only needs to be defined once. If defined multiple times, the latest defined one will override the previous ones (just like re-assigning a variable).
- In `customRange(input)`, you really want to get the corresponding `.start_date`, not just any `.start_date`. So, you should use `$(input).prevAll('.start_date')` instead of `$('.start_date')`.
- To keep the code DRY, you can reuse the datepicker options.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/YWdV7/18/.

Comment: Thanks so for the help, I'm almost there!  My actual application has additional divs (different from sample I posted).  When I go to add in additional divs, the custom range function no longer works.  See http://jsfiddle.net/YWdV7/23/  Any ideas?

Comment: It's a matter of changing the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/william/YWdV7/24/. Give yourself a break and have a read at [jQuery traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). It'll save you a lot of time in a long run.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and for the help!  I truly appreciate it!